# Learning Python the hard way : Struggling with the setup

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run Python by following the instructions in the book:

1. Go to http://learnpythonthehardway.org/wiki/ExerciseZero with your browser, get the gedit text editor, and install it.
2. Find your “Terminal” program. It's called Command Prompt. Alternatively just run cmd.

Well, actually I don't quite know what does he mean by "Command prompt" :p I looked for it but I found nothing. Help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7/Vista: Start -> type 'cmd' -> Ok

On Linux should be quite easy to find. It's usually called 'Terminal'.

- Ubuntu with Unity for example: Open the launcher -> type 'terminal' -> click it.